# Spring Webflux Stacktrace (Spring Boot 2.1.x -> 2.2.x) Issue

Tags: spring-boot, exception, stack-trace, project-reactor

I have just upgraded our Spring Boot project from the 2.1.1.RELEASE to the 2.2.0.RELEASE and observed a critical change in the stacktrace output.

I am wondering if this is intentional different or if I missed a crucial point.

**Background**

Lets say I have a WebFilter responsible for logging an http request (and its potential exception)

```
object RequestLogger : WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {

        logRequest(exchange)

        return chain.filter(exchange)
            .doFinally { logResponse(exchange) }
            .doOnError { logError(exchange, it) }
    }

   // ...

   private fun logError(exchange: ServerWebExchange, t: Throwable) {
        // t.stacktrace <------- stracktrace outpout taken from this !!!
   }
}
```

Lets say in our Domain Model an Exception is thrown. Then there is a notable difference in the stacktrace output between Spring Boot 2.2.x (latest) and 2.1.x (previous branch)

**Error Stacktrace since 2.2.0**

Contains only two lines:
- FQN of Exception class and Message
- Line occurrence of Exception

```
package.path.to.MyDomainException: The Exception Message.
package.path.to.EnsurerKt$ensure$1.invoke(Ensurer.kt:45)
```

**Error Stacktrace in 2.1.0 and before**

Contains entire stacktrace, around 50 to 100 lines.

```
package.path.to.MyDomainException: The Exception Message.
package.path.to.EnsurerKt$ensure$1.invoke(Ensurer.kt:45)
  more lines ...
reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107)
  more lines ...
io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
  more lines ...
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

**Question**

How I can get the full stacktrace outpout back again in Spring Boot 2.2.0?